# Django database (PostgreSQL) test setup and teardown for user groups not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql, testing

In setup I have:

```
    new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Sales Manager')
    SALES_MANAGER = 1
    new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Team')
    TEAM = 2
```

There a five of these groups. I then use the these variables like this:

```
    user.groups.add(TEAM)
```

In the teardown of with:

```
    Group.objects.get(name='Team').delete()
```

The first build the test database works fine, but the second produces empty group sets for all my users.

I tried not deleting the groups in the teardown, but that made now difference.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was that the auth_group_id_seq is not reset (and should not be) when I delete the groups.

I looked at the idea of resting the auth_group_id_seq in my code, but it was easier and, I would guess wiser, to adjust my testing like this:

```
    new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Sales Manager')
    SALES_MANAGER = new_group.id
    new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Team')
    TEAM = new_group.id
```

Now by test users are given the correct groups.